# libp2p for React Native: How does libp2p get around needing NodeJS' EventEmitter when used in the browser?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ipfs

So I'm trying to get run a libp2p node using React Native.

I realise that it isn't currently supported (Dec 2017 -- may have changed since) but I decided to try anyway since it already works in both the browser and NodeJS.

After requiring `libp2p` I get the error:
`` bundling failed: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `events` from `<full path>/node_modules/libp2p/src/index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map ``

This is React Native complaining that it cannot find `events`; which makes sense because it is part of the NodeJS environment and is not available in the browser (or in the React Native environment).

How is this handled in the browser? Or rather; how is `libp2p` intended to be used in the browser if they aren't bundling it at all?

The [README](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p) also mentioned a specific bundled version of the library for use in the browser, however I have given up looking for it.

Comment: Your best bet might be to just tweak `libp2p` to use a browser-compatible events library like `EventEmitter3` (https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) or `node-event-emitter` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-event-emitter). Most events libraries work very similarly, so the refactoring shouldn't be too hefty, depending on the complexity of libp2p.

Comment: I'm currently trying to create a libp2p bundle which I can babelize / webpack. Will comment with progress after festivities.

Comment: @GregLinklater any progress?

Comment: This kind of fell by the wayside for a while. Instead I've taken the lazy route and have been simulating p2p comms using a quick and dirty websocket service.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of documentation and bundling of libp2p I can only assume that you're intended to bundle it yourself.

Creating the bundle works fine -- which answers the question about use in the browser -- however libp2p in RN still does not work due to a lack of a compatible webcrypto implementation.